# php variable parameters

Tags: php

i have a function that accepts variable number of parameters (meaning I can put X around of parameters onto that function:

> MSETNX key value [key value ...]

Both key and value has to be string. Say i have another array with the following structure:

```
$a = array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3');
```

What's the most **effective** way to put $a as the parameters for the MSETNX function?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't like to use a Redis Wrapper class like [php5-redis](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/php5-redis) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function *must* take varargs, as opposed to just accepting an array,

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
  $b[] = $k;
  $b[] = $v;
}
call_user_func_array('MSETNX', $b);
```

Comment: Whoops yep. Too much Python. >.>

Comment: FYI if you want a function to support both varargs AND an array of said args, I find this sort of thing helps - `if(func_num_args()!=1||!is_array($arg)) return thisFunc(func_get_args());`. You can do fancier `call_user_func` stuff too if you don't want to use the function/class name.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way would be to simply pass the array, EG.:
`MSETNX($a);`

Comment: parameter has to be string, not array

Comment: you mean flattening the array into a string? like `MSETNX(http_build_query($a))`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear in respect of the requisite for string input;

If you need the whole parameter to be a single string, use:

```
MSETNX(http_build_query($a));
```

If you need each element (keys and values) to be converted to strings, try this:

```
MSETNX(array_combine(
    array_map(array_keys($a),"strval"),
    array_map(array_values($a),"strval")
));
```

Neither seem particularly useful to me, but perhaps you can use this combined with Amber's suggestion?